ANOVA Type (1 v 2 v 3) for Mixed ANOVA
I know things related to this question have been posted before, but they don't answer my specific situation. Additionally I've consulted with the university statistician and been unable to get an answer there.
I have a follow-up 2(treatment) x 10(day) mixed ANOVA with a severe sphericity violation (because duh it's 10 repeated measures). Yes I'm aware this should be run as an MLM, but I'm restricted to the ANOVA at the request of my advisor. My advisor runs stats in GraphPadPrism, which runs Type 1 ANOVAs with sphericity corrections by default. I use R, and we have to use R because the omnimbus test can't be run in Prism (too many factor levels). I have searched high and low and so has the statistician for packages/functions, but we cannot find a way to run Type I ANOVAs with sphericity corrections in R. You can tell R to do it and it won't throw a warning, but it also just does not apply the correction.
So that brings us to the problem at hand. Running the 2 x 10 in Prism, so Type 1 with a Greenhouse-Geiser correction, gives a significant interaction term. Running it as Type 2 or 3 in R does not return a significant interaction term. We have no missing data, so the design should be balanced. My advisor wants to know with certainty which ANOVA type is appropriate for this data because it alters the significance of the interaction term that he cares a lot about. From my reading it seems like Type 2 is not the best choice because we are interested in the interaction (although it gives the same pvalue as Type 2). But between type 1 and 3, I don't know which is the most appropriate for the data.
Thank you all so much in advance.

Yes I'm aware this should be run as an MLM, but I'm restricted to the ANOVA at the request of my advisor.---I can't imagine you can get a great answer if you are going to restrict yourself to ANOVA in light of a clearly better alternative. I will say that I am allergic to anything ANOVA in modern statistics given the many assumptions required and the inflexibility it provides for these kinds of designs.

Sorry for the advisor-driven analysis plan.   IIRC 1 vs 2 vs 3 comes into play due to unbalanced sample size, which you say your data don't gave.  Perhaps there's something else going on with the divergence in results ?
